# Scoped _t-ending names in C++

Tags: c++, posix

Does the rule about _t-ending names being reserved also apply to scoped names (e.g., types and typedefs defined within namespaces or within classes) or is it just for types and typedefs in the global namespace? Could an implementation of a standard C/C++ library or a POSIX library ever use these names as macros in its headers? (If it could, then I think that answers the first question).

Comment: Is there anything in the C++ standard that forbids the use of "_t" names?

Comment: @NicolBolas: Not that I can see.

Comment: @PSkocik: C or C++? Please pick _one_.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit This is about C++ & its interaction with POSIX C libs, as those can be used from C++. The C tag wasn't from me, and I'm not sure if it belonged.

Comment: @PSkocik: You said "*C/C++ library*". That suggests that C was involved there.

Answer (score 2):

POSIX reserves names ending in "_t" (in any context as far as I can tell) (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html) so you should not use them in any context if you are targeting POSIX systems (which pretty much just boils down to "don't use them").

Comment: Without further clarification, I think I'll play it safe and use _tp. I'll rename it later if it looks like I may. Thanks.

Comment: if you're using C++ why is it a problem with namespaces though? POSIX seems to be at odds with the C++ standard itself, which reserves the use of underscore symbols, and which is using types ending with _t